# Is the onDestroy called when the phone is power off?

Tags: android, service

I would like my application to send the signal to trigger the sending SMS method on the server side before it will be power off.

So, my app runs in the background by using service. Is its onDestroy method called when the phone is power off? Therefore, I just call the network operation method on the onDestroy of my service.

If it's not called, what should I do to call the network operation method before the phone is power off?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`onDestroy()` occurs when the Activity finishes or is being destroyed by the system. So that means that whenever the activity finishes, it is immediately destroyed. Given that when your phone powers off, all activities are shut down and therefore the `onDestroy()` method is called at that moment when the Phone shuts all of the applications and its process down.

Comment: On my phone it is not called unless I specifically call stopService. However the only way I can call stopService is in the ACTION_SHUTDOWN and when I do that the onDestroy IS called but the service restarts and nothing I do can stop the system from restarting it.

Answer (score 2):

Test it, althougt I'm pretty sure it will. What you should do if it doesn't is register broadcast receiver and look for ACTION_SHUTDOWN action.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN